# How to find the correlation between a group of values in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df:

```
ID    Var1     Var2
1     1.2        4
1     2.1        6
1     3.0        7
2     1.3        8
2     2.1        9
2     3.2        13
```

I want to find the pearson correlation coefficient value between `Var1` and `Var2` for every `ID`

So the result should look like this:

```
ID    Corr_Coef
1     0.98198
2     0.97073
```

update:

Must make sure all columns of variables are `int` or `float`

Comment: If you are are getting that last dataframe with ID Var1 only 1.0 then your input dataframe only has Var1, what are you correlating against?  Check your input df.

Comment: The df is exactly what I am showing up there. I've checked it. Could be a python version thing? When I use other groupby functions like count() for instance, I get two columns in the result Var1 and Var2

Comment: Not likely.  You have somthing else really strange going on.

Comment: I figured it out. It was reading Var2 as a string for some reason. So I just changed the type of the column to an integer and it worked.

Comment: You might want to go back and revisit Brad's solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
df.groupby('ID').corr()
```

Output:

```
             Var1      Var2
ID                         
1  Var1  1.000000  0.981981
   Var2  0.981981  1.000000
2  Var1  1.000000  0.970725
   Var2  0.970725  1.000000
```

With OP output formating.

```
df_out = df.groupby('ID').corr()
(df_out[~df_out['Var1'].eq(1)]
          .reset_index(1, drop=True)['Var1']
          .rename('Corr_Coef')
          .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   ID  Corr_Coef
0   1   0.981981
1   2   0.970725
```

Comment: When I use `df.groupby('ID').corr()` all it does is compare Var1 with itself... so I only get one column output full of 1's.

Comment: @BKS Yes, see the second part after 'With OP (original poster's) output formatting.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your answer. What is df_out? the output dataframe from the .corr function? Cause what I'm getting is just random answers.

Comment: df_out = df.groupby('ID').corr()

Comment: ok so I understood it correctly. Which brings us back to the original comment. I get an error that Var2 doesn't exit because the corr() function only compare Var1 with itself, doesn't consider Var2. The output matrix is only Var1

Comment: I'll post the resulting matrix in my answer above

Comment: Okay.  There it is.. in this case Var1 and Var2 are the same.  However, now I am using ~ and ne(1) to get rid of the self correlations.

Answer (score 15):

To get your desired output format you could use [`.corrwith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html):

```
corrs = (df[['Var1', 'ID']]
        .groupby('ID')
        .corrwith(df.Var2)
        .rename(columns={'Var1' : 'Corr_Coef'}))

print(corrs)
    Corr_Coef
ID           
1     0.98198
2     0.97073
```

Generalized solution:

```
import numpy as np

def groupby_coef(df, col1, col2, on_index=True, squeeze=True, name='coef',
                 keys=None, **kwargs):
    """Grouped correlation coefficient between two columns

    Flat result structure in contrast to `groupby.corr()`.

    Parameters
    ==========
    df : DataFrame
    col1 & col2: str
        Columns for which to calculate correlation coefs
    on_index : bool, default True
        Specify whether you're grouping on index
    squeeze : bool, default True
        True -> Series; False -> DataFrame
    name : str, default 'coef'
        Name of DataFrame column if squeeze == True
    keys : column label or list of column labels / arrays
        Passed to `pd.DataFrame.set_index`
    **kwargs :
        Passed to `pd.DataFrame.groupby`
    """

    # If we are grouping on something other than the index, then
    #     set as index first to avoid hierarchical result.
    # Kludgy, but safer than trying to infer.
    if not on_index:
        df = df.set_index(keys=keys)
        if not kwargs:
            # Assume we're grouping on 0th level of index
            kwargs = {'level': 0}
    grouped = df[[col1]].groupby(**kwargs)
    res = grouped.corrwith(df[col2])
    res.columns = [name]
    if squeeze:
        res = np.squeeze(res)
    return res
```

Examples:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), 
                    index=[1]*5 + [2]*5).add_prefix('var')
df_2 = df_1.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'var2'})

print(groupby_coef(df_1, 'var0', 'var1', level=0))
1    7.424e-18
2   -9.481e-19
Name: coef, dtype: float64

print(groupby_coef(df_2, col1='var0', col2='var1', 
                   on_index=False, keys='var2'))
var2
1    7.424e-18
2   -9.481e-19
Name: coef, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I keep getting an error when using .corrwith that I don't understand   `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in corrwith(self, other, axis, drop)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    590                                                             *args, **kwargs)
    591                     except (AttributeError):
--> 592                         raise ValueError
    593 
    594         return wrapper

ValueError:`

Comment: What does `import pandas` --> `pandas.__version__` give you?  Secondly, are there other columns to your Dataframe besides the 3 given here?

Comment: There aren't other columns. But even if there are shouldn't `df[['Var1', 'ID']]` remove them?  Also I'm using pandas 0.19.2

Comment: To your question--yes.  I'm a bit stumped, and just ran the script above after switching to 0.19.2 with no issue.  I suppose it could be an issue with Python 2.x v 3.x, go ahead and accept @Scott's answer if that does work for you.

Comment: I did get Brad's solution to work. However, I am too, am on Python 3.

Comment: I couldn't get both to work. Could be a Python 3 thing, since I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
df.groupby('ID').corr().unstack().iloc[:,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both solutions did not work for me I will post one that allows to calculate the correlation between one column in different groups for python3. This is hopefully addressing the same issue @BKS ran into.

```
data = df[['date', 'group_id', 'var1']]
data_new = data.set_index(['date', 'group_id']).unstack(['group_id'])
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data_new.to_numpy(), columns=data_new.columns)
dfCorr = final_df.corr()
```