# Python 3.x: Perform analysis on dictionary of dataframes in loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops

I have a dataframe (df) whose column names are `["Home", "Season", "Date", "Consumption", "Temp"]`. Now what I'm trying to do is perform calculations on these dataframe by "Home", "Season", "Temp" and "Consumption".

```
In[56]: df['Home'].unique().tolist()
Out[56]: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]

In[57]: df['Season'].unique().tolist()
Out[57]: ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn', 'Winter']
```

Here is what is done so far:

```
series = {}
for i in df['Home'].unique().tolist():
    for j in df["Season"].unique().tolist():
        series[i, j] = df[(df["Home"] == i) & (df["Consumption"] >= 0) & (df["Season"] == j)]
        for key, value in series.items():
            value["Corr"] = value["Temp"].corr(value["Consumption"])
```

Here is the dictionary of dataframes named "Series" as an output of loop.

[image: Image of dictionary named "series" in the loop]

What I expected from last loop is to give me a dictionary of dataframes with a new column i.e. "Corr" added that would have correlated values for "Temp" and "Consumption", but instead it gives a single dataframe for last home in the iteration i.e. 23.

**To simply add sixth column named "Corr" in all dataframes in a dictionary that would be a correlation between "Temp" and "Consumption".** Can you help me with the above? I'm somehow missing the use of keys in the last loop. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add a small sample input and the expected output. It  will make the problem clearer.

Comment: done @DanielMesejo

Comment: Mention your output in `code format`. Snapshot is not giving a clear sense,

Answer (score 1):

All of those loops are entirely unnecessary! Simply call:

```
df.groupby(['Home', 'Season'])['Consumption', 'Temp'].corr()
```

(thanks @jezrael for the correction)

Comment: it would remove the date column, which I would need while performing further steps. anyway out? and further it would create two correlation columns 1. consumption with temp 2. temp with consumption.

Comment: I think it would help if you give an example of the output dataframe you'd like to get

Answer (score 0):

One of the answer on [How to find the correlation between a group of values in a pandas dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064916/how-to-find-the-correlation-between-a-group-of-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-colu/45064951)
 helped. Avoiding all unnecessary loops. Thanks @jezrael and @JoshFriedlander for suggesting groupby method. Upvote (y).

Posting solution here:

```
df = df[df["Consumption"] >= 0]

corrs = (df[["Home", "Season", "Temp"]]).groupby(
            ["Home", "Season"]).corrwith(
                    df["Consumption"]).rename(
                            columns = {"Temp" : "Corr"}).reset_index()

df = pd.merge(df, corrs, how = "left", on = ["Home", "Season"])
```